# Mysqli::real_connect() broken pipe every 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, mysqli

I have a PHP application running on a an Ubuntu server, on NGINX.

Around every 24 hours, I get this error:

> mysqli::real_connect(): send of 73 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

The solution I have for it is rebooting. Restarting nginx, and mysql services does not fix the issue.

This is a constant thing, that happened for the last 4 days. Every morning I wake up, try to open my website, and I get this error.

*Note:*
If I try connecting to the DB using adminer or DataGrip, it works fine. But for some reason, PHP gets this error.

Comment: Does your mysql connection stay active during all the time?

Comment: No. I open a connection for each new request

Comment: Can you see if there is any error message in mysql's log file?

Comment: Could you please post the code where you're trying to connect to the database?

Comment: @weigreen Nothing on log files except for normal shutdown notes

Comment: @ChristianF Sure. https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php#L201

Comment: When your PHP cannot connect to mysql, can you connect with DataGrip as your mention?

Comment: @weigreen Yes. That is the weirdest part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CodeIgniter, in the database config you have "pconnect". If it is set to true, there can be these kind of issues.

**Fix**:

Set `config/database.php` database config param `pconnect` to be `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick search online, but it doesn't seem to be any known bugs related to this. That leaves only a handful of options, of which network or server problems are the two most likely candidates.

In either case this has nothing to do with the PHP code, and you should be able to find more information about this in the `mysql.err` file on the server.
Alternatively, you can contact your host as well, and have them check if there are some network connectivity problems.

Another common cause of the "broken pipe" error is when using `mysqldump` and the disk is full. Not sure how relevant it is for this case, but could be worth checking for any disk-related issues as well.

Comment: Happened again. Now instead of a restart, I looked at the logs. Nothing alarming. I asked a system guy to look at the logs: "First time I see this error. Nothing looks suspicious" Any other suggestion?